# Create P2SH address is not same as address saved on rpc node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinj, p2sh

I have a private key and trying to create P2SH address on testnet like my node created but they're not same. Please help me a bit, thanks so much.

PrivateKey: `c5964e19634e473e9c8fed3b149c4d44b6d62d62724035aad3eb911a1495ae27`

P2SH address from 1 threshold and 1 pubkey:
`2N4GriyLchUgwwCBonzYHgsCHNhYRHW45w7`

P2WPKH address: `2NGA8uGdnaQ21phNpVyV5uye5cbUtudxBWh` || `tb1qld2fzw9gj30wxjamsz73fug62das7cyq0em4mn`

Address from node: `2N8qKVKuR3QAy2cA5fF2QbuCpBGfGCmbUHx`

Here is more detail from `getaddressinfo`:

```
{
    "result": {
        "address": "2N8qKVKuR3QAy2cA5fF2QbuCpBGfGCmbUHx",
        "scriptPubKey": "a914aafc9f09b99cbb1ba46001ec4868ba4fb32543ca87",
        "ismine": true,
        "solvable": true,
        "desc": "sh(wpkh([a1696bdc/0'/0'/375509']02a7065a210c28d27a591e55ac6be092111349fc4b23927bb4d13c46a683bcfff7))#hrgzj3gs",
        "iswatchonly": false,
        "isscript": true,
        "iswitness": false,
        "script": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "hex": "00146da71bc5de0c0b59bbf73520df7e7d4048d02594",
        "pubkey": "02a7065a210c28d27a591e55ac6be092111349fc4b23927bb4d13c46a683bcfff7",
        "embedded": {
            "isscript": false,
            "iswitness": true,
            "witness_version": 0,
            "witness_program": "6da71bc5de0c0b59bbf73520df7e7d4048d02594",
            "pubkey": "02a7065a210c28d27a591e55ac6be092111349fc4b23927bb4d13c46a683bcfff7",
            "address": "tb1qdkn3h3w7ps94nwlhx5sd7lnagpydqfv5pyqurf",
            "scriptPubKey": "00146da71bc5de0c0b59bbf73520df7e7d4048d02594"
        },
        "label": "test",
        "ischange": false,
        "timestamp": 1561438016,
        "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/375509'",
        "hdseedid": "e2e9dd17501f967b789c28c4be1dbf64897ad8d2",
        "hdmasterfingerprint": "a1696bdc",
        "labels": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "purpose": "receive"
            }
        ]
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": 1
}
```

Comment: do you have same code for create the P2SH, if yes, can you public it?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, 
of course bro: https://pastebin.com/dL5vW22T

Comment: if possible the bitcoin RPC and the bitcoinj generated two scripts different p2shScript?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, is that true? I don't think that bro... Maybe by someway can create many p2sh address?

Comment: The address p2sh is created from the hex of the script if the script is different the p2sh address is different. ps. Yes is possible to generate much p2sh address, one script p2sh <-> address p2sh

Comment: That's because you changed your private/public key when switched method! The private key you posted has a public key starting with `033452B8` the "node" is using a public key starting with `02a7065a`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, yeah I read that can create many P2SH address depend on P2SH script, I will check more.

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast, you're right, I wrong key but out result is still not match. Correct wif is `cUNCS8F8n2dgineo4ENshEo4qFDMTLYa7MC31DKSo8whVZaV6FDu`

Comment: If your resulting address is different then it means you are using different scripts, otherwise they should be the same.